# Disable automatic activation of Gnome Shell activities on mouse over

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I have been searching for a way to disable the "hot corner" feature of the Activities button in Gnome Shell. I would prefer it to require a click such that I don't keep accidentally activating it upon mouse over.

Answer (score 12):

### For 11.10

The location of this was changed for 11.04, for 11.04 look below. You can do this with a quick edit of the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js`
If you find the code:

```
this._corner = new Clutter.Rectangle({ name: 'hot-corner',
                                       width: 1,
                                       height: 1,
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       reactive: true });
```

Change `reactive: true` to `reactive: false` and it will disable the hot corner
but still allow to activate the overview screen by clicking the Activities button or
by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows) key.

I'm going to look into making an extension to modify this behaviour instead of direct
modification of the panel.js file as it will be overwritten with updates.

### For 11.04

Same as above but edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js`:

```
this._corner = new Clutter.Rectangle({ width: 1,
                                       height: 1,
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       reactive: true });
```

Answer (score 9):

The [Activities configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) extension has an option to disable the "Activities" hotspot. It is called "Disable Hot Corner". Also, by default, the text is replaced by an icon -- this saves space.

[image: Screenshot]

Works for Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 8):

In 11.10 and later versions, you can disable the hot corner by installing the "[No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/)" extension from the official Gnome-shell extensions site.

Comment: This is the only valid answer and worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 14.10. I realize the higher-voted answers were entered earlier, but having to manually edit Javascript just to turn something off is never acceptable...

Answer (score 3):

Download `extension.js` and `metadata.json` from https://github.com/hermanus/gnome-shell-extensions/tree/master/Gnome-shell-activities-hotspot-disabler and put them in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/activitieshotspotdisabler@harmus.gmail.com/`.
The name of the directory is important -- you can change it if you change the uuid in `metadata.json` too.

This will install an extension that overrides the `Panel.HotCorner.prototype._onCornerEntered` function, so the activities screen is only shown when you click on 'Activities'. To activate it, visit https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ .

Currently, this extension works with Gnome version 3.6, that's the one shipped with Ubuntu 12.10. If you browse through the [history](https://github.com/hermanus/gnome-shell-extensions/commits/master/Gnome-shell-activities-hotspot-disabler) at Github, you will find versions that work with older Gnome releases (up to 3.0. = Ubuntu 11.04.)

Answer (score 2):

Download and open `gnome-tweaks`, go to the "Top Bar" tab and disable the "Activities Overview Hot Corner" setting:

[image]

Comment: i'm using debian 10 and there's no "Activities Overview Hot Corner" on this screen, so this answer does not work. However, there's an "Application Menu" but that's different.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.10  - the solution above works perfectly