# Modifying Key- and Mouse-Bindings for GNOME Shell

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, gnome

Is there an easy way to modify *key*- and *mouse*-bindings for GNOME shell? The `gnome-tweak-tool` is far from complete regarding these issues and the system settings doesn't include any such options. I guess there is always the possibility of opening the `[gd]conf-editor`. If that is our final resort for now what *key patterns* are involved then?

Comment: Which key bindings are you wanting to change?

Comment: I want GNOME-3 *Win* behaviour to be remapped to *Win-Enter* for example. I would also like to change the *mouse-top-left-of-screen* behaviour to be removed. I find it a bit annoying sometimes as you often accidentally reach that position when you aim for the application menu. Unity has changed this behaviour to instead trigger on left screen side except the upper-most part preventing this.

Comment: @Nordlöw Put that information in your question, that way it doesn't get buried in the comments, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the keyboard bindings, find the keyboard section in the system settings application. Under the shortcuts tab, find the shortcut that's called something like "Go into Overview Mode." Then you can change it to whatever you want.

To disable hot corner, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5573/how-do-you-disable-the-automatic-activation-of-gnome-shell-activities-button).

Comment: While there is an option listed there ("System -> Show the activities overview"), it has a default value of Alt+F1, and does not let you remove the default binding of Mod4.  So if all you want is to add a new binding you're set; if you want to remove the default binding, something else needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

All keyboard shortcuts are configured via system settings/keyboard/shortcuts.
Overlay mode can be activated with keybinding "show main menu".
There're no mouse-bindings.

Under the hood.

Standard keyboard shortcuts are stored at:

```
gconf:///apps/metacity/global_keybindings
gconf:///apps/metacity/window_keybindings
```

Modifier to manipulate windows (drag, popup menu) is at:

```
gconf:///apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier
```

Shortcuts to launch browser/email/etc at:

```
dconf:///org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys
```

Key to enter overview mode is at:

```
gconf:///apps/mutter/general/overlay_key
```

The option value is keysym (as given in xkb-config or ~/.Xmodmap), you may put "Menu" here to use menu-key to launch overview.
When assigned to other keys it may behave weird.

Comment: The overlay key is now configured at `/org/gnome/mutter/overlay-key`. By the way, how do you open gconf URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the keybindings used by Gnome Shell at the dconf location
`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`