# How to disable mouse hover at top left corner on 'Activities' action

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable the automatic activation of Gnome Shell activities button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5573/how-do-you-disable-the-automatic-activation-of-gnome-shell-activities-button)

Instead of hovering mouse over 'Activities' (top-left corner) I want only mouse click on it to open the 'Activities' Menu.  Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need gnome for these instructions:

The gnome-shell Activities corner hot-spot can disabled by installing an extesnion called "No Topleft Hot Corner." Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/ . To install it, you just click "on" at the top of the page next to the name of the extension.

An earlier answer states that this can be accomplished "by editing some code - fortunately this doesn't need recompilation...

To do this:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
```

Scroll down to this section in the file and comment out the line highlighted i.e. put `//your_initials` in fron t of `this._hotCorner...`:

[image]

Save, logout and login."

Comment: should I comment  this._hotCorner = new Layout.HotCorner();  line and the line below it i.e   container.add_actor(this._hotCorner.actor);

Comment: In my testing, commenting out just this line in the screen shot disabled the hotcorner activation.  The reason why I didnt want to comment out "...new Layout" because you will have an unallocated variable - this may/probably will cause issues/crashes for any related code in that file that attempts to use that variable.