# Is it possible to reveal the Gnome3 launcher just by moving the pointer near the left hand side?

Tags: launcher

Is it possible to reveal the Gnome3 launcher by just moving the mouse to the left hand side of the screen?  Sometimes I just want to quickly flick my mouse to the left to reveal the launcher, but instead I have to go up to Activities and then down to the launcher.

Comment: Does the info about disabling it from this question help? [Disable automatic activation of Gnome Shell activities on mouse over](http://askubuntu.com/q/5573)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try flicking the pointer to the very upper left corner of your screen? That's how it works in Debian, at least.

Comment: Yeah that works but I don't want to do that, I want to just flick it to the left of the screen to reveal the launcher.  Seems a bit odd having to go diagonally up and left and then down rather than just being able to go left and reveal.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The "Activities Overview" only can be activated using the upper left corner of the screen or clicking in the "Activities" label in the same quadrant. I think you could get this behavior with extensions but isn't in my knowledge anything like this.

Comment: Cheers.  I did have a browse for an extension but couldn't find anything.  There must be a way to do it though!