# How to get the Gnome Activities overview to only open when clicked on

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, activities-overview

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 (with Gnome Shell obviously), and I have noticed that sometimes when I quickly hover over the Activities button in the top-right-hand corner, that it opens the Activities overview. Although when moving my mouse over it slightly slower, nothing happens. But sometimes I accidentally move my mouse there, and it opens up that area, and I am now getting really annoyed with accidentally opening it up. So I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that the Activities overview only opens up if the Activities button is clicked on?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: Just found old question as well: [Disable automatic activation of Gnome Shell activities on mouse over](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5573/disable-automatic-activation-of-gnome-shell-activities-on-mouse-over)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [Activities Configuration](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/). You can disable the hot corner and there are plenty of other settings.

Open the URL via Firefox browser to install the extension directly.

After that, open the Tweak Tool for the configuration

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want modify aspects of Gnome Shell, you can use extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/

In this case (with shell versions 3.8 to 3.18 currently), you can use [No Topleft Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) extension *(you can install by going the page and clicking 'Install', you will need the Gnome Shell Integration plugin installed and enabled in the browser)*. This functionality is also available in some other extensions.