# Activities configurator not working after upgrade to GNOME 3.18

Tags: gnome, customization, extension, 15.10, activities-overview

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 to 15.10, and also upgraded to GNOME 3.18, however I now have a problem, I want to rename the `Activities` button to `Activities Overview` and I also want to stop the Activities Overview from launching when I mouse over the button in a certain way.

Now before I had GNOME 3.18 I used the GNOME Shell extension described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/653429/364819) to configure and customize what I have talked about. However this is what I noticed today:

[image]

So is there a similar way to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/657744/364819) to fix the problem? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to change the supported version as described in your linked answer, but that's not necessary, because GNOME 3.18 is supported. Usually you should see an <kbd>Update</kbd> button in the tweak tool. I have no idea, why not in this case.

But you could also use [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) link to deactivate and activate/update the <kbd>Activities Configurator</kbd>.

---

Or the hard way

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/activities-config@nls1729/
```

and install the extension again. To do that, open [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) link in your Firefox and activate the extension.

Close and open the tweak tool to see the updated extension.